# Logging into new FTP server, but no directories show up

Tags: debian, ftp, sftp, chmod, chown

I've tried this with both ProFTPD and SFTP. I'm trying to chroot a user to /var/www/user however when I log in to the FTP server with their account, I get "/var/www/user: No such file or directory". However, I can assure you it exists. It then throws me into the root directory, however, this is completely empty, but it is not, obviously.

Comment: Does the user in question have read and/or execute permission on the permissions of the `/var`, `/var/www`, and `/var/www/user` directories?